How to prove/disprove these two formulations of Lagrange inversion formula are equivalent
I have once stumbled at comprehending the original form of Lagrange inversion formula:
If $z=f(w)$, then $$
f^{-1}(z)=a+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\lim_{w\to a}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left[\left(\frac{w-a}{f(w)-f(a)}\right)^n\right]\right)\frac{(z-f(a))^n}{n!}
$$ where $a$ is an arbitrary chosen point that $f$ is analytic at $a$ and $f'(a)\ne 0$
and tried to derive it myself as follows using Taylor series:
Let $y=f(x), g(y)=g(f(x))=x$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dg}{dy}&=\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}=(1)\left(\frac1{\frac{dy}{dx}}\right)=\frac1{f'(x)}\\\\
\frac{d^ng}{dy^n}&=\frac d{dy}\frac{d^{n-1}g}{dy^{n-1}}=\frac d{dx}\frac{d^{n-1}g}{dy^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac1{f'(x)}\cdot\frac d{dx}\frac{d^{n-1}g}{dy^{n-1}}
\end{align*}
$$
With these $n$th-order derivatives, we can write $g(y)=f^{-1}(y)$ as
$$
g(y)=a+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(y-f(a))^n}{n!}\left[\left(\frac1{f'(w)}\cdot\frac d{dw}\right)^{n-1}\frac1{f'(w)}\right]_{w=a}
$$
where $a$ is an arbitrary chosen point that $f$ is analytic at $a$ and $f'(a)\ne 0$ as in the original formula, and $\left(\frac1{f'(w)}\cdot\frac d{dw}\right)^{n-1}$ denotes $n-1$ times of recursively taking its derivative w.r.t $w$ and then multiplying by $\frac1{f'(w)}$.
The latter form resembles the original inversion formula, but with $\left(\lim_{w\to a}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left[\left(\frac{w-a}{f(w)-f(a)}\right)^n\right]\right)$ becoming $\left[\left(\frac1{f'(w)}\cdot\frac d{dw}\right)^{n-1}\frac1{f'(w)}\right]_{w=a}$
The calculations using both formulations do match, but I found it difficult to prove that they are indeed equivalent. The $n=1$ case is obvious from the definition of differentiation, and I have succeeded in proving the $n=2$ case though:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{w\to a}\frac d{dw}\left[\left(\frac{w-a}{f(w)-f(a)}\right)^2\right]&=\lim_{w\to a}2\frac{w-a}{f(w)-f(a)}\cdot\frac d{dw}\frac{w-a}{f(w)-f(a)}\\\\
&=2\cdot\frac1{f'(a)}\cdot\lim_{w\to a}\frac{f(w)-f(a)-(w-a)f'(w)}{(f(w)-f(a))^2}\\\\
&\stackrel{\text{L'H}}=2\cdot\frac1{f'(a)}\cdot\lim_{w\to a}\frac{-(w-a)f''(w)}{2(f(w)-f(a))f'(w)}\\\\
&=-\frac1{f'(a)}\cdot\lim_{w\to a}\frac{w-a}{f(w)-f(a)}\cdot\lim_{w\to a}\frac{f''(w)}{f'(w)}\\\\
&=-\frac{f''(a)}{f'(a)^3}\\\\
\left[\frac1{f'(w)}\cdot\frac d{dw}\frac1{f'(w)}\right]_{w=a}&=\left[\frac1{f'(w)}\cdot\frac{-f''(w)}{f'(w)^2}\right] _{w=a}\\\\
&=-\frac{f''(a)}{f'(a)^3}
\end{align*}
$$
How should I approach to prove the equivalence, or if they are in fact not equivalent, how to disprove that as well?
